# Implementing the new nextjs 13 fetch cache in a non-nextjs app?

Tags: caching, next.js, cdn, next.js13

If we had to implement the request [cache and cache revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating) in an application using another SSR react framework or even in a non-react app, how hard it would be to implement? Is there any ecosystem that facilitates that (that is, for instance, platform-independent as next)?

Obs: I'm talking about the granular caching. I know we can just do the same as Incremental Static Regeneration does and just revalidate a static cached page, but I'm talking about having each individual request used in SSR cached, so that, even if one of them expires, only that one will be revalidated.